# Auth::user returns random user object

Tags: laravel

I'm having a very strange problem that I don't know what the cause could be.

I have a Laravel 7 project configured with the standard Auth Scaffolding. This was working **without** issue until just recently. I noticed I was unable to login to my project (redirected back to home).

During my investigation of what the cause could be I created a test route to return
`Auth::check();`

Auth::check would return **true** even though no one was logged in.

I did another check with
`Auth::user();`

This is where things get weird. Here is a sample output of Auth::user()

```
    {
       "first_name":"Titus",
       "last_name":"Senger",
       "email":"casper.kuhic@example.org",
       "username":"vwolff",
       "country":"pa",
       "biography":"Sed quod ad corporis quasi. Repellat tempora quo ab ut. Molestiae iure qui illo recusandae rerum iure vitae quasi. Odit ipsam ut laudantium et sed consequuntur ab non.",
       "category_id":3,
       "social":{
          "facebook":"",
          "instagram":"",
          "twitter":"",
          "linkedin":"",
          "youtube":""
       },
       "avatar":[
    
       ],
       "banner":[
    
       ]
    }
```

It appears to be faker data of a user object but with **no user id**. If I refresh the route, I get another user object returned with **completely different** user data.

I thought maybe this could be returning random user data in my database as I did use a seeder/factory to create a bunch of random user accounts for testing my app. I ran
`php artisan migrate:refresh`
Now I confirmed that all my tables were empty, including the users table. Navigated to my test route and sure enough, still generating random user object on each refresh of Auth::user().

What is happening!? I have no idea what would have caused this. This **is not a production build** yet. Everything is still being worked on locally.

I have also tried rolling back several commits from github to where I know Auth was working properly and the issue seems to persist **even with older versions of my code**.

```
composer.json

    {
        "name": "laravel/laravel",
        "type": "project",
        "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
        "keywords": [
            "framework",
            "laravel"
        ],
        "license": "MIT",
        "require": {
            "php": "^7.2.5",
            "doctrine/dbal": "^2.10",
            "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
            "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
            "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.5",
            "laravel/cashier": "^12.1",
            "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
            "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
            "laravel/ui": "^2.0",
            "nassajis/laravel-resumable-upload": "^1.2",
            "php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg": "^0.16.0",
            "predis/predis": "^1.1",
            "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^4.1",
            "spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^8.0.0",
            "spatie/laravel-permission": "^3.13",
            "stripe/stripe-php": "^7.45",
            "ticketpark/wsc-rest": "^1.2"
        },
        "require-dev": {
            "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
            "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
            "laracasts/generators": "^1.1",
            "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
            "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
            "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
        },
        "config": {
            "optimize-autoloader": true,
            "preferred-install": "dist",
            "sort-packages": true
        },
        "extra": {
            "laravel": {
                "dont-discover": []
            }
        },
        "autoload": {
            "psr-4": {
                "App\\": "app/"
            },
            "classmap": [
                "database/seeds",
                "database/factories"
            ]
        },
        "autoload-dev": {
            "psr-4": {
                "Tests\\": "tests/"
            }
        },
        "minimum-stability": "dev",
        "prefer-stable": true,
        "scripts": {
            "post-autoload-dump": [
                "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
                "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
            ],
            "post-root-package-install": [
                "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
            ],
            "post-create-project-cmd": [
                "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
            ]
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

The only thing that I recently did that may or not somehow influence this issue is changing session_driver to use database and run a migration for sessions table. I have rolled back the change and updated my session_driver to use file again, but I am still having problems.

Additional Things I've tried doing:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Returning `User::all()` retrieves an empty array `[]`

**EDIT 2**

It appears Auth::user() is some how looking at my factory as I have now commented out the user factory and receive this error when trying to view my test route:

```
Unable to locate factory for [App\User].
```

I also cannot restart my server or clear cache anymore because I receive the same error:

```
Unable to locate factory for [App\User].

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\html\sodisting\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\FactoryBuilder.php:273
    269|      */
    270|     protected function getRawAttributes(array $attributes = [])
    271|     {
    272|         if (! isset($this->definitions[$this->class])) {
  > 273|             throw new InvalidArgumentException("Unable to locate factory for [{$this->class}].");
    274|         }
    275| 
    276|         $definition = call_user_func(
    277|             $this->definitions[$this->class],

  1   C:\xampp\htdocs\html\sodisting\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\FactoryBuilder.php:296
      Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\FactoryBuilder::getRawAttributes([])

  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\html\sodisting\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\GuardsAttributes.php:155
      Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\FactoryBuilder::Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\{closure}()
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is that your normal seeding is done with yor testing seed?

Comment: What does your test-code look like? Any middleware running? Any other route that might hit before your test route?

Comment: @Aless55 After I refreshed my database, I did not run any other seeder. Database is completely empty but I still get returned random user data.

Comment: @kerbh0lz my test route is very simple. I don't think anything would interfere with it. No custom middleware.

`Route::get('/t', function(){
    return Auth::user();
});`
``

Comment: restart your server and clear the cache and then test it again

Comment: Do you use an addiitional DB for testing? What happens if you display all users like return User::all() ?

Comment: @NaveedAli I restarted my app/server and ran `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan config:clear` no improvement

Comment: @Aless55 No additional database. I do have redis configured for my broadcast driver, but my session driver is set to file. User::all() returns an empty array

Comment: @scheric1 that is strange, because without any users your current user should obviously be null. The only thing imaginable is that something with your cache/session is going wrong.

Comment: Do you have a "user" factory in place that would generate above output (and gets triggered somehow)? If so, can you change something in that factory and rerun your test route to see if the changes made in the factory reflect in the output?

Comment: @Aless55 I know, I just don't get it. The only thing I did recently switched my session driver from file to database while testing something. I then switched it back and remove the migration file for the sessions table. Do you think that some how could be affecting things?

Comment: @kerbh0lz I don't see how my user factory could be triggering. The only reference to my user factory is in my UserSeeder.php file but I need to run that manually to trigger it

Comment: Me neither, maybe leftover test code you forgot to remove somewhere. "_I get another user object returned with completely different user data._" This and the fact that your user table is actually empty sounded like a factory could run and output its data. Just a guess

Comment: @kerbh0lz well you are right in the fact that the factory is somehow getting called. I just commented out the entire factory file and now when I run my test route I get `Unable to locate factory for [App\User].` I just don't know how or why it is trying to call the factory for Auth::user()

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Turns out there was a reference in my AppServiceProvider to the factory. Some leftover test code that I completely forgot about. I feel stupid.

Thanks everyone for their help in trying to solve this with me.